# Laravel V4.1.0: 401 code "message": "Unauthenticated." for API

Tags: laravel, unauthorized

I am facing a problem with calling Laravel API when not using `php artisan serve`
I have used `Passport` for authentication

When I use `php artisan serve` and login using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login` it works fine and when I take the token and fetch data using `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getData` it works fine also.

But, I want to make it run **without** `php artisan serve`. When I tried that:

login using `http://127.0.0.1/Laravel/MyApp/public/index.php/api/login` works fine and when I take the token and fetch data using `http://127.0.0.1/Laravel/MyApp/public/index.php/api/getData` it gives `401 code - unauthorized`.

I am using `AppServ : Apache`.

I searched SOF and tried all suggested solutions with no luck.

api.php

```
Route::post('/login','App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiAuthController@register');

Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth:api','namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::post('getData', 'DataController@index');
});
```

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
..........
}
```

kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

             \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,

            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

gurads:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

my `.htaccess` inside public dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$ 
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried to copy public directory data to the root folder and editing the `.htaccess` .
Also I tried creating new `.htaccess` in the root folder with and without removing `.htaccess` in the public folder with no luck also.

This is the Login:
[image: Login]

This is php artisan serve result and it works fine
[image: php artisan serve result]

This is when not using php artisan serve
[image: when not using php artisan serve]

Thanks

Comment: what's os you use?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: you can configure out by using virtualhost if you don't want to run php artisan serve everytime.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b

Comment: @AhmedRagab You can go to public and then type in the terminal `php -S localhost:8080` but the questions is why don't you wanna run `artisan`?

Comment: is the mod-rewrite module enabled?

Comment: Basheer Kharoti : Yes I know that. But I want to use it as a link to host it on shared host and to deal with it easier without the need for external commands

Comment: aimme: yes and it is replying me.
The problem is the authorization

Comment: Sok Chanty: Thanks. But this isn't my problem.